# How to generate a 384-bit Symmetric Key Size in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

I'm doing research on a cipher that take in a larger symmetric key size than 256-bits which is 384? Is there a way we could generate a symmetric key using something like a KDF (or anything else for that matter) that is 384 bits. I tried using a `Key Generator` in java and did `keyGenerator.init(384)` but it supports only up to 256-bits. Do you think I could combine a 128-bit symmetric key with a 256 bit one generated from Key Generator in Java? I'd want to avoid having to try to use a hashing function, iterating it a lot, and trying to add my own random salts to it. I know this is an uncommon question as no one would be looking for a 384-bit symmetric key size. I'm not looking for a KDF in particular, just a simple and strong way of generating a random symmetric key. My use case doesn't involve getting something with low entropy like a user's password and making it a key.

Comment: KeyGenerators are algorithm-specific: if your algorithm is not supported in a registered Provider there's not much point in using a KeyGenerator. Really, the whole of the JCA is based around the provider architecture, it won't do you much good to create an instance of `java.security.Key` if your home grown cipher classes can't do anything with a `Key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think I could combine a 128-bit symmetric key with a 256 bit one generated from Key Generator in Java?

Of course, you just retrieve the bytes using `getEncoded()` for both 256 and 128 bit keys, combine the two returned `byte[]` in one `byte[]` using `Arrays.concat`, and then use `new SecretKeySpec` on the result.

> I'd want to avoid having to try to use a hashing function, iterating it a lot, and trying to add my own random salts to it.

If you would have 256 bit source material then you could use HMAC with the source material as the key and any information (even the empty message) as HMAC input. If you would use SHA-384 - as already suggested - then the output would be a neat 384 bit of keying material which could be used as input for `SecretKeySpec`.

And yes, using PBKDF2 with SHA-384, a static or even empty salt and a single iteration (iteration count of 1) would work as well. But that's already mentioned in [the other answer by Saptarshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042348/589259).

> I know this is an uncommon question as no one would be looking for a 384-bit symmetric key size.

Well, there is the SIV mode of operation that cheats and uses a key that is really made up out of two consecutive keys. So there is precedent even for symmetric ciphers.

If a block or stream cipher directly uses a 256 bit key then I would probably call it snake-oil as there is no sense in going over 256 bit even if quantum computing becomes a reality.

---

In the end a secret key for a symmetric cipher is simply (pseudo-)random bits - with DES keys that include parity bits the odd one out. So if the cipher is not JCA compatible - i.e. you don't really need a `SecretKey` object instance - you could just generate a 48 byte array, fill it with `SecureRandom` bytes and be done.

Comment: Why is only 1 iteration necessary? I thought several iterations would be better for strengthening the key. It seems I misunderstood and didn't really understand the concept of "entropy". I don't need any user input like a password for creating a key. I just need a random key for a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES. Generating a key using `Secure Random` would have higher entropy than using PBKDF. I understand now that supplying a password is meant to be used when its necessary like creating user password. From my use case I think generating a random 48 byte array would make more sense.

Comment: It would be great if you could please clarify the reason for an empty salt and iteration count 1. I thought iterations should be several thousands depending on the system power and also salt has to be random for security. Isn't that what PBKDF2 says? Or it is not required in the context of this particular question?

Comment: Exactly that, you'd be using the Password Based Key Derivation function as a *Key Based* Key Derivation Function, and that doesn't require an iteration count. A random salt may strengthen it, but should still be considered optional.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `SecretKeyFactory` class with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA384` algorithm. You'd find the details in documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html#SecretKeyFactory-javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactorySpi-java.security.Provider-java.lang.String-).

The code would look like this:

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
random.nextBytes(salt);
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, 
   keyLength);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = 
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA384");
SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(),
    "AES");
```

It is better to clear the `SecretKeySpec` and `SecretKey` after use to avoid exposing the keys with a heap dump. As of Java 8, there is no easy way to do that as the implementations of these two interfaces do not seem to have implemented the method `destroy()` of the interface `Destroyable`. So use reflection to clear them after use.

Comment: There's no reason to use that particular hash function, PBKDF2 is capable of generating 384 bits of key material with any common secure Hmac.

Comment: @James K Polk Would it be better to do something like this: `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmac")`.

Comment: I don't see why that would be better. PBKDF2 is for generating key bits from a *password* or similar low-entropy source. If you just want a random 384 bits of key, use something like `byte [] key = new byte[384 / 8]; new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);`

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'd use PBKDF2 without blinkin' an eye, but I'd made sure that my `char[]` would simply have the byte values in the least significant bits and of course make sure that the `char[]` and possibly previous `byte[]` would be destroyed after use. Saptarshi, you go out of the way to destroy the keys, but the source material would also need to be destroyed in that case, of course. Also you generate a strong random salt (why?) and you don't specify the iteration count (to have value 1).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: You'd use PBKDF2 on what?

Comment: On a `byte[]` converted to a `char[]` holding the original key. The problem with the question is that it asks for a KDF in the title and then goes on about key generation in the body of the question. So it is not clear which one is meant. A KDF is not a key generator and a key generator is not a KDF either.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I mentioned KDF function because I was looking for an easy way to generate a strong symmetric key and I wasn't sure what I was looking for. I don't actually need a "KDF" just a secure way of generating a random key with no inputs (because I realized they aren't needed for my use case). So it looks like generating a random byte array using `SecureRandom` would be the best option for the highest entropy.

Comment: That's fine of course. However, I would suggest that you do not put such suggestions for an answer into the title of your question, if you put it in the question at all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ok I updated the post. In the future I won't suggest things like that and just explain my requirements more clearly for the best answer.